# My new tire went bad n a week im scare to move my car little metal pieces are poking out

Tags: tires

I got my tire rod fixed and a new tire now my car won't turn back right it shakes n my tires a wearing fast

Comment: what is your question,you have given some information but not asked a question,my advice is to not drive your car and to get it towed in for repair.what kind of mechanic do you use i think he has some explaining to do.

Comment: I would suggest that whoever did the tie rod replacement didn't set the steering / suspension geometry properly.  If it were mine, I'd be in touch with the mechanic who did the work and have them collect, repair and return the vehicle at their expense.  I would ask though, could you change your post into the form of a question please?

Answer (score 2):

From what you have described the repairs on this car were NOT performed properly and I agree, it's NOT SAFE to drive it in this condition.  Get it towed to a qualified service facility and it sounds like the one who did the original work is not qualified.